# Ejecutar un método nada más inicializar un objeto

Tags: java, poo, objeto

Quisiera saber si existe alguna manera en Java de ejecutar un método nada más inicializar un objeto.

Mi idea es: Al crear un objeto, que nada más crearlo, se ejecute un método privado del propio objeto que permita leer de un fichero para inicializar las propiedades de este objeto.

Querría mantener la misma estructura de la clase, tanto los getter como el método read privado. Porque, como solo tengo que leer en esa clase, no lo necesitaría público.

```
private void read(){
    long lNumeroLineas = 0;
    try {
        FileReader fr= new FileReader("/Users/jesussmariscal/Desktop/Theater_APP/play.txt");
        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(fr);
        String s;
        do  {
            s=br.readLine();
            if (! s.equals("/n")){
                lNumeroLineas++;

                if (lNumeroLineas==1) {
                    this.title=s;
                    String[] tituloSeparado = this.title.split(":");
                    this.title=tituloSeparado[1];
                }
                if (lNumeroLineas==3) {
                    this.description=s;
                    String[] descripcionSeparada = this.description.split(":");
                    this.description=descripcionSeparada[1];
                }
                if (lNumeroLineas==2) {
                    this.image=s;
                    String[] imageSeparada = this.image.split(":");
                    this.image=imageSeparada[1];
                }
            }
        }  while (!s.equals("null"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Porque tengo los siguientes métodos:

```
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
```

Y no querría meter dentro de cada getter la función de read() para no saturar y porque es redundante. Es por ello que me gustaría saber si existe alguna manera que me permita que nada más crear un objeto de esa clase, se ejecute ese método dejándolo como privado.

Comment: ¿Llamar el método en el constructor? ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Pues es cierto. Solo se me había ocurrido en cada getter llamar al método read(). Pero sabía que algo ahí fallaba porque era redundante no solo leer datos que no necesitaba para ese método; sino también leerlos varias veces.

Comment: Crea el método privado que quieres y llámalo desde el constructor, esa me parece la mejor opción. También podrías investigar algo sobre la anotación @PostContruct

Comment: Creo que la manera más rápida y efectiva va a ser llamarlo desde el constructor. Porque solo lo voy a necesitar emplear una única vez durante toda la vida de ejecución del programa. Así que gracias.

Answer (score 0):

> A constructor is used in the creation of an object that is an instance of a class. Typically it performs operations required to initialize the class before methods are invoked or fields are accessed.
>
> ---
>
> Un constructor se usa en la creación de un objeto que es una instancia de una clase. Normalmente realiza las operaciones necesarias para inicializar la clase antes de invocar métodos o acceder a campos.
>
> [Oracle tutorial constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctor.html)

Un constructor se ejecutará una única vez en cada instancia, además, será la primera "acción" que el objeto ejecutará, es decir, al momento de crear un objeto este invocará a su constructor, si no le has especificado uno, ejecutará un constructor vacío.

## Clase main

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        DummyClass dummyClass = new DummyClass();
    }
}
```

### Clase dummy

```java
public class DummyClass {
    public DummyClass () {
        sayHello();
    }
    private void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

Verás que al momento de crear una instancia de `DummyClass` accionará el método `sayHello`, puedes verlo mejor si cambias tu main a:

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    new DummyClass();
    new DummyClass();
    new DummyClass();
    new DummyClass();
}
```